# Component-Entity-System - Input Handling

Tags: c++, components, sfml

I'm using an entity-component-system (ECS) framework to make a 2D space shooter. My components are data-only, my systems handle all logic, and entities are basically IDs.

**Here are some of my components:**

```
struct LaserCannon {
    bool shooting;
};

struct Thrusters {
    bool up, left, right, down;
    float acceleration;
};

struct Movement {
    sf::Vector2f velocity, acceleration;
    float maxSpeed;
};
```

I am using a pretty cool input system built by one of the SFML developers, called [thor](http://www.bromeon.ch/libraries/thor/tutorials/v2.0/actions.html). It maps inputs like `sf::Keyboard::W` to my own higher-level events like `Control::UP`. I can check if an event fired via `inputMap->isActive(Control::UP)` and then respond appropriately.

This brings the *raw input* 'up' one abstraction level - but I need to go a bit further. I need entities to be able to respond to things like `Control::UP` and activate resultant entity-level things like activating the player ship's thrusters. **I haven't done this yet, because I don't know how to approach it using components and systems!**

**I've come up with one possible solution:** I could create a new component called PlayerShipController, which has booleans representing all of the things I want to control. I could then have a system that reacts to input and sets those booleans accordingly like so:

```
struct PlayerShipController {
    bool up, left, right, down, shoot;
};

// Input handling system
struct InputSystem : public entityx::System<InputSystem> {
    InputSystem(std::shared_ptr<thor::ActionMap<Event>> inputMap) : inputMap(inputMap) {}

    void update(entityx::EntityManager &es, entityx::EventManager &events, entityx::TimeDelta dt) override {

        // Iterate across all entities with a PlayerShipController
        es.each<cm::PlayerShipController>([dt, this](entityx::Entity entity, cm::PlayerShipController &controller) {
            if (inputMap->isActive(Event::LEFT_BUTTON)) {
                controller.left = true;
            }
            if (inputMap->isActive(Event::UP_BUTTON)) {
                controller.up = true;
            }
            if (inputMap->isActive(Event::RIGHT_BUTTON)) {
                controller.right = true;
            }
            if (inputMap->isActive(Event::DOWN_BUTTON)) {
                controller.down = true;
            }
        });
    };
    std::shared_ptr<thor::ActionMap<Event>> inputMap;
};
```

But I am wondering if there are other, perhaps better ways to achieve this. What I really don't like about my solution, is that it requires me to write a system that is very specific to the game (it needs a *PlayerShipController* - waaay too specific I think!)! I think it would be much neater to have a sort of mid-layer.. To me, the solution below is much cooler!

1. User presses 'w'
2. 'w' is translated to `Control::UP` by the thor inputMap
3. `Control::UP` is somehow mapped to entity-level events like `Ship::THRUST_UP`, for only the ships controlled by the user
4. Entity-level events like `Ship::THRUST_UP` are translated into actions like activating the `Thrusters::up` boolean

What is especially cool about this solution, is that I would ideally be able to use the same entity-level events to control many other things, like an asteroid exploding, or an enemy ship using thrusters. I just don't now how to implement it, or integrate it into ECS. How might I do this?

Answer (score 2):

One idea would be to set up an event dispatcher so that when the key events are polled as you are doing above, they can be sent to any game entity that has subscribed to the specific event. EntityX has built-in event objects that will allow you to do this. Have a look [here](https://github.com/alecthomas/entityx/blob/master/entityx/Event_test.cc).